# Node.js performance's analysis through flame graph (on Mac)

Tags: xcode, node.js, performance, flamegraph

> Flame graphs are a visualization of profiled software, allowing the
>   most frequent code-paths to be identified quickly and accurately — [Brendan Gregg on flame graph](http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html)

Using `node --perf-basic-prof` with Xcode Instruments (*on Mac*) should help to generate a flame graph for performance analysis. Following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/zeusdeux/aac6f8500917319213c5), it's rather easy:

1. made node.js 0.12 generate a `perf-<pid>.map` using `node --perf-basic-prof app.js`
2. record a stack using Xcode instruments time profiler (*exported as `profile.csv`*)
3. generate a flame graph with [Brendan Gregg perl tools](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph), using `./stackcollapse-instruments.pl profile.csv | ./flamegraph.pl > graph.svg`

Sadly, the generated flame graph does not benefit from the `perf-<pid>.map` thus leaving method adresses instead of their name (`1cfc9a09b880` instead of `LazyCompile:~ /node_modules/benchmark/benchmark.js:1870`).

Is there any way to give the mappings / symbols to Xcode instruments, to made it generate a csv file with method names (*[this doesn't work](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/Instruments_help_articles/RestoringSymbolsWhenTraceShowsOnlyAddresses/RestoringSymbolsWhenTraceShowsOnlyAddresses.html)*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done through the ui of the [node flamegraph module](https://github.com/thlorenz/flamegraph).

*ps. [a pull request](https://github.com/thlorenz/flamegraph/pull/12) offers to add the option to the npm command line tool to allow typing `flamegraph -t instruments -f profile.csv -m perf-4499.map -o flamegraph.svg`*